# For each line of a Data.Frame, get the column name where a value is TRUE

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data.frame `L1States_df` that looks like this:

```
  BoltOn CutOn IdleOn PumpOn
1  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2  FALSE FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
6  FALSE FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
```

For each line of `L1States_df`, there can either be one or no (zero) TRUE, the rest will be FALSE.
I would like to create a new vector which contains, for each line:

- the name of the column associated to TRUE (if there is a TRUE on that line)
- NA if there isn't any TRUE on this line

Sample desired output:

```
   State
 1 NA
 2 "IdleOn"
 3 "IdleOn"
 4 "IdleOn"
 5 "IdleOn"
 6 "PumpOn"
```

I've tried:

```
apply(L1States_df,1,function(x) names(which(x==TRUE)))
```

but that doesn't generate the `NA` when there's no `TRUE` on the line, so I put an `IFELSE`:

```
apply(L1States_df,1,function(x) ifelse(is.null(names(which(x==TRUE))),NA,names(which(x==TRUE))))
```

Is there a better/faster way, or is there an predefined function that does this sort of thing (maybe `data.table`)?

**Extra points:** although it should never happen, just for peace of mind: how could I get a NA generated if there's more than one TRUE on a particular line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is

```
m <- as.matrix(mydf)
replace(NA, row(m)[m], colnames(m)[col(m)[m]])
# [1] NA       "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "PumpOn"
```

And for the bonus points, you can use `match` to generate the `NA` on rows with more than one TRUE

```
match(rowSums(mydf) > 1, TRUE)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized possible solution (without the need in `apply`)

```
indx <- which(L1States_df == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
names(L1States_df)[indx[match(seq_len(nrow(L1States_df)), indx[, 1]), 2]]
## [1] NA       "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "IdleOn" "PumpOn"
```